# What's the difference between "has been living" and "has lived"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, tense, present-perfect, present-continuous

Here I know I have one present perfect and present perfect continuous sentence.

- I have lived in Europe for 2 years.
- I have been living in Europe for 2 years.

Can you use both of them interchangeably? What is the exact difference between them? To me both suggest that the person is still living in Europe.

Answer (score 6):

The two are interchangeable if you intend a *continuative*<sup>†</sup>  reading: that you have lived in Europe for the two years leading to the present moment.

> <sup>ok</sup>I have lived in Europe for two years, and will not leave until next year.
>    <sup>ok</sup>I have been living in Europe for two years, and will not leave until next year.

But if you intend an *existential*<sup>†</sup>  reading, signifying that you lived in Europe for two years on at least one occasion in the past, you cannot use the progressive construction:

> <sup>ok</sup>I am widely travelled: I have lived in Europe for two years, in Brazil for nearly five, and in Singapore for three.  *BUT*
>   <sup>∗</sup> I am widely travelled: I have been living in Europe for two years, in Brazil for nearly five, and in Singapore for three.

---

<sup>†</sup>For a somewhat more detailed description of these distinct uses of the perfect, see [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially [§3.2 Pragmatic meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32).

<sup>∗</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable*

Comment: Can we use 'had lived' instead of 'have lived' in the third sentense in the pink boxs?

Comment: @JBL No, because the main-clause verb is in present tense and your 'Reference Time' (the time you are talking about) is the **present**; but the eventualities expressed with a past perfect have to be prior to some **past** Reference Time.

Comment: The continuous and non-continuous have different emphases.

Comment: @Lambie Maybe you can explain the different emphases?