# Question past perfect, action/state finished

Tags: present-perfect

Does the sentence "I have been married for five years" mean that I am still married?

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question. If you use the [edit] link to tell us what research you have done on this subject, you are more likely to receive a useful answer. Please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you will ask more questions, and with more details!

Comment: Quick answer, "yes", although, as the other comments suggest, you really ought to add more to your question.

Comment: @Andrew If you work quickly, you can still post an answer before the question is closed.

Comment: This is not a duplicate  because the other question stipulates a context using ***since a specific date***. This question uses ***for a certain number of years***. This creates a different grammatical context.

Answer (score 1):

No  it doesn't necessarily mean that. The meaning has to be interpreted by such things as the speaker's intention and the context of the utterance.

To take a different example:

> I've lived overseas for five years.

This does not necessarily mean that the speaker  still lives overseas.   It could mean that the speaker, over his lifetime, has lived overseas   for a total of five years. The speaker could be replying to an advertisement that requires applicants to have lived overseas for (at least)  five years. This has nothing to do with whether the applicant is currently living overseas.

The same with your sentence.

> I have been married for five years.

What this sentence means has to be inferred from the speaker's intent and the context. Whether or not the speaker is still married is not determined solely  by the use of the present perfect.

See also [What's the difference between "has been living" and "has lived"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29982/whats-the-difference-between-has-been-living-and-has-lived)